# Schema.org type for ordered lists?

Tags: schema.org

What would be the proper Schema.org type for marking up ordered lists?

For instance, statistical rankings for sports player.

Comment: The format of the HTML isn't what matters. It's the content. That determines what mircrodata format is needed. [I don't see one fore this specific example](http://schema.org/docs/schemas.html).

Comment: I came across an [ItemList](http://schema.org/ItemList) which resides under the Think -> CreativeWork nodes.  Would this work?

Comment: That looks pretty good, actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Schema.org’s [ItemList](http://schema.org/ItemList) for the list.

In case of "statistical rankings for sports player": If you list the statistics of several players, each entry should be a separate item. You could use [Person](http://schema.org/Person).

Example in Microdata:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemList">
<meta itemprop="itemListOrder" content="Descending" />
<ol>
  <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">…</li>
  <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">…</li>
  <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">…</li>
</ol>
</div>
```

---

Note that a [sports vocabulary](http://blog.schema.org/2014/02/schemaorg-sports-vocabulary.html) was proposed recently, which

> includes support for describing sports statistics

So maybe there will be some more appropriate classes.