# What Schema.org type should be used for latest news?

Tags: schema.org

My website publishs news and articles. But in homepage I have just 2 sidebar. In one of them I publish 10 lastest news.

Now I want to know what type of Schema.org should be used for this IMPORTANT sidebar? Should I use 'sidebar'?

Also in one of my pages, I publish links to all articles. Should U use for these pages the 'blog' type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of your news is a [`CreativeWork`](http://schema.org/CreativeWork). Probably the more specific [`Article`](http://schema.org/Article), maybe the more specific [`NewsArticle`](http://schema.org/NewsArticle).

For the list, you could make use of [`ItemList`](http://schema.org/ItemList) (see an [example](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/58471/17633)), but this is not required (I’d only do that if the list and its ordering have to be available in Microdata). You could simply use HTML’s `ul` and be done with it.

If you think this is more like a blog (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18716097/1591669) about `Article` vs. `BlogPosting`), you could use [`BlogPosting`](http://schema.org/BlogPosting) with [`Blog`](http://schema.org/Blog) as parent.